# Log @ConfigurationProperties in SpringBoot prior to startup?

Tags: java, spring-boot, listener

I'm trying to find a way to log my application properties (injected into my beans via @ConfigurationProperties) prior to the context startup so that I can see what the exact properties are before all the beans are initialized.

I've tried to create a Listener on an ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent, but there is no way to retrieve all the properties defined short of retrieving individual properties one at a time.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Some way to initialize `@ConfigurationProperties` first and log their contents, or retrieve all the application startup properties prior to the context creation?

Comment: I am not sure I get what you're trying to do. Either way, the actuator can help. There is the `/env` endpoint that lists the configuration files that were loaded and their content and `/configprops` that gives you an overview of the actual configuration of each `@ConfigurationProperties` bean. Not sure what you're after but that'd be a good start.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll I'm trying to log/display all my configs prior to the context being refreshed. For example, I have JTA beans, etc that are auto config upon startup, so if a connection fails, I want to be able to see what the config properties were prior to the bean being initialized.  This isn't a we app, so the context paths don't help.  Additionally, if the spring context fails to load (invalid bean config, failed validations, etc) I want to be able to see exactly what params were used.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll I took a look at the actuator bean for JMX exposure of the config props but as I suspected, it retrieves the beans from the app context to display their values.  My problem is that I want to log this info prior to the context being refreshed; if a bean fails during instantiation due to incomplete or incorrect config values, I'd like to see what the values are.  Same issue if I try to use the `@PostConstruct` method- it is called after the context is refreshed.  I'm surprised there is no spring logger that I can enable to see these values as they get set.

Comment: you can create an issue to share that idea with the team.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see application properties simply with the help of a custom class implementing the ApplicationListener and defining it as one of the startupup class in spring-factories entry so they will execute before the application load. Steps are as follows :- 
a) Create a file called spring.factories in resource classpath i.e. src\main\resources\META-INF\spring.factories with content -

```
# Application Listeners
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=demo.CustomConfigListener
```

b) Create a custom listener class in your proj like here CustomConfigListener

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.core.env.EnumerablePropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;


public class CustomConfigListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
            for(PropertySource<?> source : ((ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) event).getEnvironment().getPropertySources()){
                if(source.getName().equals("applicationConfigurationProperties")){              
                    if (source instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
                        for(String name : ((EnumerablePropertySource) source).getPropertyNames()){
                            System.out.println(name+" :: "+ ((EnumerablePropertySource) source).getProperty(name));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        }       
    }

}
```

c) Your custom ConfigurationProperties class

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(ignoreUnknownFields = false, prefix = "mail")
public class MailProperties {    
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private Smtp smtp;    
    //Getters & Setters

    public static class Smtp {    
        private boolean auth;
        private boolean starttlsEnable;    
        //Getters & Setters
    }
}
```

d) Finally your application.properties

```
mail.host=localhost
mail.port=25
mail.smtp.auth=false
mail.smtp.starttls-enable=false
```

Comment: May mention the [Spring Boot application reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context) ?

Comment: Actual implemented code are always better than any short reference guide from clarity perspective

Comment: Thanks!  You gave me the piece I was missing.  I figured it had to be an `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` but wasn't able to figure out how to grab the values from that point.  Although I do find it odd that several of the property values are repeated 2 or 3 times in the Enumeration, but it is good enough for my needs.  Although I would say that your step 1 is optional; I can instantiate add the Listener via `SpringApplication.addListener()`.

Comment: @LoganMzz I had read the docs; I had seen the listeners.  As I mentioned in the post, I had already created a Listener, but couldn't figure out how to get the values from within it.  This answer gave me the exact piece I was missing.

Comment: If you happen to have an active profile or more. How do you only log the relevant properties (i.e. those that are overridden)?

Comment: You can avoid the instanceof check by implementing `ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>`.

Comment: In my case I see system properties, servlet properties but don't see my custom properties(TS asked exactly about it).

Answer (score 5):

As a followup to @Avis' answer, I realized that the snippet didn't include any command line args, etc, so I have updated his concept a little.  I am attaching my logger class in case it has value for anyone who lands on this question in the future.

```
public class ConfigurationLogger implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {
    // slf4j logger
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigurationLogger.class);

    // used to sanitize any password sensitive keys (copied from Spring Boot's Sanitizer() class
    private Sanitizer sanitizer = new Sanitizer();

    // store the config keys in a sorted map
    private Map<String, Object> configurationProperties = new TreeMap<>();


    /**
     * Trigger upon all events during startup.  Both ApplicatoinEnvironmentPrepareEvent and
     * ApplicationPreparedEvent need access to the same configurationProperties object.  Could
     * have done this through separate events, both extending an abstract base class with a static
     * hash map, but not worth the effort.  Instead have the same class listen for all events, and 
     * delegate to the appropriate method.
     */
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) {
            // store the values
            onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent((ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent) event);
        }else if( event instanceof ApplicationPreparedEvent){
            // display the values
            logConfigurationProperties( (ApplicationPreparedEvent)event);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store the properties in the hash map for logging once all property sources have been read
     * 
     * @param event
     */
    private void onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        for (PropertySource<?> source : event.getEnvironment().getPropertySources()) {
            if (source instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
                for (String key : ((EnumerablePropertySource) source).getPropertyNames()) {
                    Object value = ((EnumerablePropertySource) source).getProperty(key);
                    if (!configurationProperties.containsKey(key)) {
                        configurationProperties.put(key, sanitizer.sanitize(key, value));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print all the config properties to the logger
     */
    private void logConfigurationProperties( ApplicationPreparedEvent event) {
        logger.debug("Application started with following parameters: ");
        for( Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : configurationProperties.entrySet()){
            logger.debug("{} :: {}", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```

And the listener is initialized in the SpringApplication main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);
        // add configuration properties logger
        app.addListeners(new ConfigurationLogger());
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```